# create a stop with Jquery for viemo embedded video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, vimeo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop a Vimeo Video with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688275/stop-a-vimeo-video-with-jquery)

I have a video embedded into the hero section of my site, streaming from my vimeo account. I'm trying create a Jquery stop function to my embedded video, Therefore when the user clicks on any  of the links on my site the hero video stops playing. Is there a way this can be done?

[click here](http://thisiswired.com/test/index.html)

Comment: You're stating vimeo in the post and YouTube in the headline?

Comment: Possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688275/stop-a-vimeo-video-with-jquery, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145990/how-to-stop-a-vimeo-video-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your linked site uses vimeo, I'll direct you here: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js

A stop (pause) is as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('myViddy').pause(); //for <object>-style embed
```

and

```
document.getElementById('myIFrame').postMethod({"method": "pause"}); //for <iframe>-style embed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the vimeo javascript API, it allows you to control what the player does: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js Look at this page for an working example of controlling the vimeo player through javascript: http://player.vimeo.com/playground

Edit: My bad, was a minute too late while struggling with the captcha.